# Count the number of ways of putting balls into bins

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

In this task you are given an odd number of white balls and the same number of black balls. The task is to count all the ways of putting the balls into bins so that in each bin there is an odd number of each color.

For example, say we have 3 white balls. The different ways are:

```
(wwwbbb)
(wb)(wb)(wb)
```

for the two different possibilities.

If we have 5 white balls the different ways are:

```
(wwwwwbbbbb)
(wwwbbb)(wb)(wb)
(wwwb)(wbbb)(wb)
(wb)(wb)(wb)(wb)(wb)
```

You can take the input, which is a single integer, in any way you like.  The output is just a single integer.

Your code must be fast enough so that you have seen it complete for 11 white balls.

You can use any language or library that you like.

Comment: Please clarify, can our output be just the number of different ways? That is, a single number as output?

Comment: @orlp I think that is what Lembik meant. There are also only 705432 possible combinations disregarding the rules of odd numbers only for 11 balls of each colour

Comment: @orlp Yes a single number. Having said that, it would be very interesting to see the  list of possible assignments of balls in bins if anyone wanted to show those too.

Comment: I assume this is from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2736933/how-many-ways-to-get-an-odd-number-of-each-color-in-each-bin You should cite it @Lembik

Comment: I think you should take out the speed criterion or make it more specific. "Fast enough" is too vague.

Comment: You know that PPCG users are crazy enough that they would rather spending money on using a supercomputer to compute it for 11 than taking 1 more byte? So why wasting their money? `:)`

Comment: `rather spending money on using a supercomputer` only apply for [tag:code-golf], though

Comment: [relevant to current conversation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107660/39244)

Comment: (remark: It's possible to calculate P function efficiently with a [complicated formula](http://fredrikj.net/blog/2014/03/new-partition-function-record/). It may be possible to calculate this function too, with a suitable formula.)

Comment: I have added this to the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS) as sequence [A302919](https://oeis.org/A302919).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pari/GP, 81 bytes

```
p=polcoeff;f(n)=p(p(prod(i=1,n,prod(j=1,n,1+(valuation(i/j,2)==0)*x^i*y^j)),n),n)
```

For more efficiency, replace `1+` with `1+O(x^(n+1))+O(y^(n+1))+` (the first `O` term alone already helps a lot).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc1BCsIwEAXQvSf500ZsBJc5gzcIBNvYCWUSQpX29DEtiluFv3h/MfOTy3y8p1I8hEyK0y0O3uOLHHuw0UrUzrATusXTTQ83cxTwKagzGdNRs1huVhuISMmWMv759orFQlpNVLl@@NvYIWWWGR663rzLiEst5QU) (earlier 86 byte version with a pair of unneeded parens and without the `p=` abbreviation)

#### Old version, 90 bytes

```
f(n)=polcoeff(polcoeff(taylor(1/prod(i=0,n,prod(j=0,n,1-x^(2*i+1)*y^(2*j+1))),x,n+1),n),n)
```

Computing `f(11)` needs a bigger stack size, the error message will tell you how to increase it. It's more efficient (but less golfy) to replace the two `n` that appear as second arguments to `prod` with `(n-1)/2`.

Comment: Works up to 13 for me!

Comment: I guess that is with the version using `(n-1)/2`?

Comment: Yes, good point.

Comment: Out of interest, do you think it's possible to compute f(500)?

Comment: It takes a few minutes to compute f(500)=214621724504756565823588442604868476223315183681404

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, 108 bytes

```py
C=lambda l,r,o=():((l,r)>=o)*l*r%2+sum(C(l-x,r-y,(x,y))for x in range(1,l,2)for y in range(1,r,2)if(x,y)>=o)
```

Recursively enumerates all sets, making sure to not get duplicates by always generating the sets in order. Reasonably fast when memoized using `C = functoools.lru_cache(None)(C)`, but this is not necessary for `n = 11`.

Call `C(num_white, num_black)` to get your result. First couple of `n`:

```
1: 1
3: 2
5: 4
7: 12
9: 32
11: 85
13: 217
15: 539
17: 1316
19: 3146
21: 7374
```

To generate the results:

```py
def odd_parts(l, r, o=()):
    if l % 2 == r % 2 == 1 and (l, r) >= o:
        yield [(l, r)]

    for nl in range(1, l, 2):
        for nr in range(1, r, 2):
            if (nl, nr) < o: continue
            for t in odd_parts(l - nl, r - nr, (nl, nr)):
                yield [(nl, nr)] + t
```

E.g. for (7, 7):

```
[(7, 7)]
[(1, 1), (1, 1), (5, 5)]
[(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (3, 3)]
[(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)]
[(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 3), (3, 1)]
[(1, 1), (1, 3), (5, 3)]
[(1, 1), (1, 5), (5, 1)]
[(1, 1), (3, 1), (3, 5)]
[(1, 1), (3, 3), (3, 3)]
[(1, 3), (1, 3), (5, 1)]
[(1, 3), (3, 1), (3, 3)]
[(1, 5), (3, 1), (3, 1)]
```

Comment: Very nice indeed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>180</s> 172 bytes

```python
def f(n):
 r=range;N=n+1;a=[N*[0]for _ in r(N)];R=r(1,N,2);a[0][0]=1
 for i in R:
  for j in R:
   for k in r(N-i):
    for l in r(N-j):a[k+i][l+j]+=a[k][l]
 return a[n][n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU9BCoMwELz7ir01aRS03gzpE3LwGkIJ1LRRWSXYQxHfniahLcxhZ3Z2mF3f23PBNoT7YMESpF0BXniDj4FLgazhRih5VrW2i4cbOARPJNW8F540pSwvlJu4jRBNAcnkkqmPOZmNf5bp9E2oHM1aFuefONLOqIk5rWY2aiYiiaOOlYbt5RGMQh0R0hHmo1Q09mjrFLd6hxuxpx0PqK6wp3@OEw0f)

Straightforward implementation of the generating function. Long but (somewhat) efficient. O(n<sup>4</sup>) time, O(n<sup>2</sup>) memory.

The resulting array `a` contains all results of all sizes up to `n`, although only `a[n][n]` is returned.

Comment: What does your code calculate for even n, out of interest?  As in a[4][4].

Comment: This is the fastest solution so far too!

Comment: @Lembik a[4][4] = Number of ways to put 4 white balls and 4 black balls into bins, each bin has an odd number of white balls and an odd number of black balls. Exacly as in the defintion.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <del>168</del> 181 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
r,p=range,product
def f(n):
 a,R=eval(`[[0]*n]*n`),r(1,n,2);a[0][0]=1
 for i,j in p(R,R):
  for k,l in p(r(n-i),r(n-j)):a[k+i][l+j]+=a[k][l]
 return a[-1][-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7BjsMgDETvfIVvhcZIJXvrKv2IXBFS0ZbskqYGubRqvz6FrDSW7CfNePK7/CXq13XidINYApeUljvEW05c9oIxD@zpN2DmdHn8FHEJE0yS1FGAx3EIT7/Is7UHt6eqs0KWBgl79e0rrBqMgCkxRJwhEmQ54tjcG7zi8g9Zko7NTHpW6ujttYvOLt3suqEedXUCOJQHE3irjWuztghqAa@tpOzxy9TXNT1zpAKkDcJOn3a4dV4/)

- Based on [user202729's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162331/58557).
- **Edit:** Made it an independent function.
- Saved 2 bytes thanks to [user202729](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69850/user202729).

Comment: This is a snippet (assumes `n` contains the input) You should either add `def f(n):` or `n=input()` (to make it a function/full program resp.)

Comment: And... this is Python 2, you can use a tab instead of two spaces. Saves a byte. The `a` can be `eval(\`[[0]*n]*n\`)` (where `\`` stands for `repr`).